# configuring existing eclipse java project to build using gradle

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I have an existing Java project in Eclipse. I want to implement builds using gradle. I tried using the gradle eclipse plugin as given  [here](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/eclipse_plugin.html) but ran into numerous errors in Eclipse.

I am using gradle 1.3, and I tried running gradle from command prompt, but I get compilation errors.

So my question is, does anyone know of some good resource which offers a how-to for converting an existing java project in Eclipse to compile using gradle. I also have some dependencies on other projects. The link to the tutorial I have given is not really helpful.

UPDATE:
I can get gradle to work if my project doesn't have dependencies on other projects. However, if it does refer to some other project, I can't figure out how to reference another project? I have added the referenced project dir to repositories but I still get "class does not exist" errors. My gradle file is as below:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

version='1.0-SNAPSHOT'

def repositoryPath = 'C:/Users/AMoody/workspace/temp/temp-protocols/'

repositories{
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs repositoryPath
    }
}

dependencies{

    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.+'
    compile 'junit:junit:4.+'
     testCompile 'junit:junit:4.+'

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first couple of chapters of the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html), along with the many (Java) samples in the full [Gradle distribution](http://www.gradle.org/downloads), should get you started. It doesn't matter all that much whether your current build is Eclipse or something else; to be successful with Gradle, you'll first have to master its fundamentals.

Once you have the Gradle command line build working, you can give the IDE integration another shot. Depending on your preferences, you can either generate IDE files with Gradle's [Eclipse plugin](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#eclipse_plugin) (again see the samples in the full Gradle distribution), or use the [Eclipse Gradle Integration](https://github.com/SpringSource/eclipse-integration-gradle) for a more integrated IDE experience.

Check out the [Gradle homepage](http://www.gradle.org/learn) for additional resources. When faced with a concrete question about Gradle's build language, consult the [Gradle DSL Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html). A full-text search over the single-page [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html) can also be quite effective. Last but not least, make sure to visit the [Gradle Forums](http://forums.gradle.org).

Comment: Thanks. I will give this a try. I am having problems with dependencies, but I will give it another shot and get back to you.

Comment: I found a good resource as given here: http://www.breskeby.com/2010/10/1-gradlecast-getting-started-with-gradle/

Comment: See "project dependencies" in the user guide.

Answer (score 44):

Okay, So if you have simple java project which has dir/file structure as below

[image]

**Step-1:** create file name `build.gradle` in project root directory as below

[image]

**Step-2:** add following gradle script in `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
archivesBaseName = 'someJar'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT' 

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.test.Run'
    }
}

dependencies {
   compile  'log4j:log4j:1.2.16'
}
```

**Step-3:** close or delete from eclipse this project and import it again while selecting Gradle project as below

### [image]

### [image]

Now your project hierarchy will look like this. (Also note its added Gradle Dependencies while importing project)

[image]

**Step-4:** Create source foler `src/main/java` in project and move your all packages in that source folder.

[image]

**Step-5 last but not the least:** *Cheers :)*

So now your Simple Java project has converted into Gradle project!

Comment: The option to import a Gradle project doesn't exist for me in Eclipse... is there an Eclipse plugin I need?

Comment: Yes you can download `Gradle` plugin only to have this option, If I am not wrong then you must have Eclipse of Java SE. You need to download `Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers` that will have import gradle option in there.

Comment: I download the elasticsearch source code, import to the eclipse, when I click the 'build model' why the eclipse start to download the gradle.2.2.1.bin ? I have already install the gradle.2.12(config the GRADLE_HOME and path). Which config file or setting indicate the downloading?

Comment: Worked on Eclipse Mars 4.5.2 but I do not see the Gradle Dependencies in the tree view

Comment: @Guillaume, i am wonder if you have `Enterprise Edition` and still not seeing?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, since it actually solves the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try Eclipse integration for Gradle: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/buildship-gradle-integration