# Open build.gradle in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm going to use the Facebook SDK in my application. I must open the build.gradle and add the following code:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

But where in Eclipse can I open this for my project? I have googled, but can't find any relevant information.

Comment: Open your build.gradle file? Just look for it in your project view. If you have an Android application one is created for you automatically.

Comment: If you are using eclipse then you don't require build.gradle

Comment: You need the Gradle plugin. CHeck this link: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGradle/article.html

Comment: If you don't have a build.gradle file because it's on old project, get Android Studio and import your project. Eclipse works only partially with current projects because it is no longer supported. http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2014/12/android-studio-10.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add gradle plugin to eclipse and then configure your project to use gradle. For more reference check out the answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14616328/3541465

OR

You can add Facebook sdks manually in eclipse. First import the Facebook sdk in eclipse then add it into your project.