# How to resolve import in Eclipse?

Tags: java, maven

Im new in Java development and not familiar with various kinds of import (Maven, Git, etc), so I make it simple:

```
import com.google.common.collect.*;
import com.google.gson.*;
```

These two is not resolved in code Im inspecting, and I have no idea what kind of actions I should take neither what I should import to resolve it but it is probably some popular library.

Is there complete guide how developers import packages in eclipse (for example C# developers use Nuget, despite there is a ton of hand made ones), or they really use all this enormous import selector?

Comment: maven, gradle,... there are tons of frameworks for this. To keep it simple, just add  google's jars to your project, right click --> build path --> Add

Comment: Well, either you use some dependency management tool like Maven and add a dependency to those two external libraries or you download the jars and add them to your project in Eclipse, then right-click the project and choose Build Path --> Add External Archives

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all **Mavenise** your current project and add the following dependency to it:

Goto: POM.XML after converting your current project to Maven project.

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

      <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
      <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

      <properties>
       ------Properties Here----
      </properties>

      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>4.12</version>

        </dependency> 

          <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-collections</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-rc2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
--------Add your Dependencies here, remember you have to add dependencies under <dependencies> here </dependencies> ----------
      </dependencies>
    </project>
```

Search for all dependencies here: https://mvnrepository.com/ , incase you need more dependencies to import.

**How to mavenise your current Java Project:**

*In your eclipse just right click on Java Project and click Configure and you should see “ Convert to Maven Project ” option.*

What is **POM.XML**

A Project Object Model or POM is the fundamental unit of work in Maven. It is an XML file that contains information about the project and configuration details used by Maven to build the project. It contains default values for most projects. Now, you can add a dependency in pom.xml.

Comment: Ok, I see, Maven is pretty popular, so how to "Mavenise" it? It is standalone or plugin for eclipse?

Comment: yeah, Eclipse -> Help -> Install New Software.
Expand " Collaboration " tag.
Select Maven plugin from there.
Click on next .
Accept the agreement & click finish.

Comment: @eocron In your eclipse just right click on Java Project and click Configure and you should see “ Convert to Maven Project ” option.

Comment: Ok, I managed to transform it, dependencies added manully or is there some button in Eclipse?

Comment: @eocron , there will be a POM.xml file, add dependencies to it under

Comment: @eocron, was you able to do it?

Comment: Not yet, trying to find out why pom.xml is missing.

Answer (score 1):

If you use no dependency management tool like maven the simplest way is just download corresponding JARs and add them manually: http://www.oxfordmathcenter.com/drupal7/node/44

For GSON use this: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.3.1

For the second dependency I suppose you should use GUAVA:
https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/UseGuavaInYourBuild

or this: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.collections/google-collections/1.0-rc2

But actually better to convert your project to Maven project (as described for example here: https://crunchify.com/how-to-convert-existing-java-project-to-maven-in-eclipse/) so that you'll be able to use pom.xml for dependency management or Gradle (see [configuring existing eclipse java project to build using gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14615872/configuring-existing-eclipse-java-project-to-build-using-gradle)) and avoid manual JAR download